# Detecting the invoking object from within a report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Is there some way I can detect, from within a report, which form invoked the report?

I have a form for selecting several criteria which are used to build the WhereCondition for various reports. In the report On Load, I test for the calling form being open. If it is open, I grab the selection criteria for display in the report header. If it isn't open, I display things like "Species: All" instead of, for example "Species: Blue-tailed damselfly". That works ok in this particular case but it feels a bit flaky. I would prefer to know what it was that invoked the report, in case in some future more complex system, a report could be invoked from different places. I know that a parent form is available from within a subform but that doesn't apply in this situation.

Comment: You can't detect, but you can store on opening. Simplest solution: pass the forms name with `OpenArgs`. or you can create your own `OpenReport` method that stores the calling forms refernce and the reports reference in a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form where the user selects the criteria used to build the *WhereCondition* which is used to filter the report.  Do not ask the report to re-examine the form criteria in order to generate the appropriate header for itself.  Build your header string in the same form procedure which builds the *WhereCondition*.  Then pass that string as *OpenArgs* when you call `OpenReport`.

For example, if no restriction is placed on species:

```vba
strHeader = "Species: All"
```

Or for the selected species:

```vba
strHeader = "Species: Blue-tailed damselfly"
```

Then pass `strHeader` when you open the report:

```vba
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="YourReport", _
    View:=acViewReport, _
    WhereCondition:=strWhere, _
    OpenArgs:=strHeader
```

And in the report's load event you can check whether you got something in *OpenArgs* and use it:

```vba
If Len(Me.OpenArgs) > 0 Then
    ' do what you want with it '
End If
```

This approach makes the report independent from any particular form.  The strategy does not break if you rename the current form or create a different form for report selection criteria.

You could even designate an appropriate header when report criteria are standardized in advance.  For example, a command button captioned "View Yesterday's Additions":

```vba
strWhere = "[Date_Added] >= (Date() - 1) AND [Date_Added] < Date()"
strHeader = "Species Added Yesterday"
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="YourReport", _
    View:=acViewReport, _
    WhereCondition:=strWhere, _
    OpenArgs:=strHeader
```